# How to find numbers in file JSON and put newline using python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I have a `JSON` file containing string data. I want to find '1.' up to '.' and add a newline after '.'
The input's like this:

```
My mom goes to market today, she buys 1. Apples at the fruit store. 2. Beef at the meat shop. 3. Knife at the material shop. 4. She back home at 8 a.m. 5. But she forgets to buy Vegetables. 6. And she backs to market again. 7. And finally, she buys everything that she needs.
```

And I want the output's like this:

```
My mom goes to market today, she buys 
1. Apples at the fruit store. 
2. Beef at the meat shop. 
3. Knife at the material shop. 
4. She back home at 8 a.m. 
5. But she forgets to buy Vegetables. 
6. And she backs to market again. 
7. And finally, she buys everything that she needs.
```

And the output becomes .docx file.
Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have your string in a variable I would iterate over it, as you can loop over characters.

You want to know when there's a number followed by a dot

```py
my_string = 'My mom goes to market today, she buys 1. Apples at the fruit store. 2. Beef at the meat shop. 3. Knife at the material shop. 4. She back home at 8 a.m. 5. But she forgets to buy Vegetables. 6. And she backs to market again. 7. And finally, she buys everything that she needs.'


# Helper function to check if the character can be casted to an integer
def RepresentsInt(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

new_string = ''

# We enumerate so when we find a number we can access 
# the following char and check it's a dot
for i, char in enumerate(my_string):
    if RepresentsInt(char):
         if my_string[i + 1] == '.':
             new_string += ('\n' + char)
         else:
             new_string += char
    else:
        new_string += char
```

Then replace the value of `my_string` with `new_string`

```py
new_string = 'My mom goes to market today, she buys \n1. Apples at the fruit store. \n2. Beef at the meat shop. \n3. Knife at the material shop. \n4. She back home at 8 a.m. \n5. But she forgets to buy Vegetables. \n6. And she backs to market again. \n7. And finally, she buys everything that she needs.'
```